# How to restart dataTaskPublisher after failure?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have some code that makes a request to the net when the count value changes

```
@Published var count: Float = 0

init(data: SomeData) {
///
   $count
      .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
      .filter { return $0 != self.product.quantity }
      .setFailureType(to: APIProviderError.self)
      .flatMap { val -> AnyPublisher<Cart, APIProviderError> in
            return self.cartService.update(item: params)
         }
      }
      .sink { result in
         print(result)
      } receiveValue: { cart in
         print(cart)
      }
      .store(in: &cancellable)
///
}
```

The cartService.update return dataTaskPublisher.

**When any error is returned, the flatmap is never called again.**
Can I restart it?

Comment: Side note: instead of filter you can use the `removeDuplicates()` publisher.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I restart it?

No. In the Combine framework, when a pipeline fails, the whole pipeline is cancelled and the publisher is done.

However, inside your `flatMap` you can build a mini-pipeline that does a `catch` and prevents the failure from escaping into the outer pipeline. You would then be able to keep using the outer pipeline if desired.

Also, if you think it will do any good, you can prevent the error from promulgating with a `retry`, which will try the fetch again. A data task publisher only fetches once, unless a `retry` makes it try again.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. Do you have a link to the documentation about the lifecycle of publishers ? Thanks !

Comment: You could just read my whole "book" on Combine. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/toc.html